# Storing variables with Javascript Object Literals

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm playing around with Paul Irish's DOM-based routing pattern (http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/) as a way to organize my code.

My question is: how do I store / call-back variables I want to use throughout my site with this approach?

Usually I would just do something like:

```
var $button = $('.button');
var $link = $('.link');
```

How can I integrate the above storing of variables into the following pattern?

```
NS = {
   common : {
     init: function(){
       $button.doSomething();
      }
   },
   home : {
     init: function(){
        $link.doSomethingElse();
      }
   },
   utils : {
     init: function(){}
   }
}

UTIL = {

  fire : function(func,funcname, args){
  // indicate your obj literal namespace here
  var namespace = NS; 

  funcname = (funcname === undefined) ? 'init' : funcname;
    if (func !== '' && namespace[func] && typeof namespace[func][funcname] == 'function'){
      namespace[func][funcname](args);
    }

  },

  loadEvents : function(){

    // get body id
    var bodyId = document.body.id;
    var classNm = document.body.className;

    // fire up common
    UTIL.fire('utils');
    UTIL.fire('common');

    //fire up page specific js
    UTIL.fire(bodyId);
    UTIL.fire(bodyId,classNm);
  }

};

// kick it all off here 
$(document).ready(UTIL.loadEvents);
```

Comment: Mhh, as you do it with any other object literal. `NS.home.init();` or to store `NS.home.init = function(){};`

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I want to store site-wide elements in variables so that I can access them anywhere in my javascript file..

Comment: Have you considered using other javascript frameworks? I've been using http://knockoutjs.com/ lately and the base viewModel can be extended to hold the functions. Kind of like inheriting from an object. -HTH

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, you should be able to do the following.

```
NS = {
    domElements: {
        $button: null,
        $link: null
    },
    common : {
        init: function(){
            if (NS.domElements.$button === null) {
                NS.domElements.$button = $('.button');
            }
            var $button = NS.domElements.$button;
            $button.doSomething();
        }
    },
    home : {
        init: function(){
            if (NS.domElements.$link === null) {
                NS.domElements.$link = $('.link');
            }
            var $link = NS.domElements.$link;
            $link.doSomethingElse();
        }
    },
    utils : {
        init: function(){}
    }
}
```